# ArrayList isn't printing out

Tags: java, arraylist, linked-list, arrays

I have created two arrays. I added them up. Then I wanted to print out the new array by defining a method. But the method can't print out the array. Where is the error in my code?

```
package stringpractice;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class StringPractice {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] boy = {"John", "Russel", "Ryan"};
        List<String> l1 = new LinkedList<String>();

        for (String x : l1) {
            l1.add(x);

        }

        String[] girl = {"Sara", "Leena", "Emilia"};
        List<String> l2 = new LinkedList<String>();
        for (String y : l2) {

            l2.add(y);
            l1.addAll(l2);
            l2 = null;
            printMe(l1);

            /*removeStuff(l1, 1,2);
             reverseMe(l1);
             */
        }

    }

    public static void printMe(List<String> l1) {
        for (String p : l1) {
            System.out.printf("%s ", p);
        }
        System.out.println();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The for-loops walk through the still empty lists.

```
   for (String x : boys) {
        l1.add(x);
   }
```

Or

```
   Collections.addAll(l1, boys);
```

Setting l2 to null will not loop well. And the addAll can be done outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to print in your list. You need to change

```
for (String x : l1) // l1 don't have a single element
                    // at this moment
```

and

```
for (String y : l2) // same as l1
```

To

```
for (String x : boy)
```

and

```
for (String x : girl)
```

Again

```
 l2.add(y);
 l1.addAll(l2);
 l2 = null; // inside for lopp l2 become null
```

So you will get `NPE` from here.

Corrected code

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] boy = {"John", "Russel", "Ryan"};
    List<String> l1 = new LinkedList<>();
    for (String x : boy) {
        l1.add(x);
    }
    String[] girl = {"Sara", "Leena", "Emilia"};
    List<String> l2 = new LinkedList<>();
    for (String y : girl) {
        l2.add(y);
        l1.addAll(l2);
        printMe(l1);
    }
    l2 = null;
}

public static void printMe(List<String> l1) {
    for (String p : l1) {
        System.out.printf("%s ", p);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your both the `List` `L1` and `L2` are empty. so your both the `for` loop body is not executed.

Answer (score 0):

public class StringPractice {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    String[] boy = { "John", "Russel", "Ryan" };
    List<String> l1 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(boy));

    String[] girl = { "Sara", "Leena", "Emilia" };
    List<String> l2 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(girl));

    l1.addAll(l2);
    l2 = null;
    printMe(l1);

    /*removeStuff(l1, 1,2);
     reverseMe(l1);
     */

}

public static void printMe(List<String> l1) {
    for (String p : l1) {
        System.out.printf("%s ", p);
    }
    System.out.println();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You arent traversing the `boy[]` and `girl[]` array anywhere. You need to iterate like `for (String x : boy)` for some result.

Comment: your answer helps, thats what I wanted. unfortunately i can't acccept two answers at the same time. Otherwise I put ur answer as accepted too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate through the boy[] and girl[] array in order to print there contents